# Set interface name without msg in ROS2

Tags: ros2, messages, custom-message

When creating custom message types in ROS1 (noetic), I can store the `*.msg` files in a subfolder named `msg`. In the CMake file, I just type the name of the file without `msg/` in `add_message_files(...)`. The resulting message type is named as `<pkg_name>/<file-name (without .msg)>`

When creating interfaces in ROS2 (foxy), I have to type the file name in my CMake file including the relative path in `rosidl_generate_interfaces(...)` like `msg/<filename.msg>`. The resulting interface name also includes `msg`: `<pkg_name>/msg/<file-name (without .msg)>`, but actually I don't want the exact path as an interface name.

So my question is: Is it possible to store the files in the `msg` folder for a better folder structure but set the name of the resulting interface differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *can* change the destination of any files produced by CMake (using, for example, the [`configure_file()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html)).

But... *should* you? I'm not convinced that you should. I think you'll find you have cleaner code if you allow messages to be explicitly stored alongside only other messages. Further, having a standard behavior for generated files is very useful for other developers: anyone using your package will assume
that messages will take place in a standard location. Even in the cases where nobody else will use your code, the ROS tools you're running on your computer will often make this assumption.

As an experiment, try changing the files manually (using the `mv` command or your file explorer) and see what breaks. I think you'll find that this ends up being messier than you initially bargained for.